# how to open multiple windows from the controller in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

How to open multiple windows from the controller?

For example, I have a controller that gets all the clients and for each client I want that his info is displayed in a different window or tab. 
Is that possible using asp.net MVC 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done this exact thing, it was based on a button click which would fire multiple windows based on the parameters. Here's what you could do. Your controller would be like this...

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CopyOpportunitySave(CopyOpportunityViewModel model)
    {
          ViewModel model = new ViewModel();

         foreach (var url in "List object that contains URLS")
        {                            
            model.ClientURLs.Add(url);
        }


        return View("CopyOpportunity", model);
    }
```

So now your Model class will have a property like 
`public List<string> ClientURLs{get; set;}`
which is populated by all the URLs you will need to do a window.Open.

and Now in your view you can say

```
  @foreach (var u in ViewModel.ClientURLs)
  {  
    <script>
    window.open(u);
    </script>        
  }
```

just as long as the script inside the foreach loop is getting executed, it will work

Comment: The window.open will not work if I pass an actionlink with a view and an object...it shows all in the same window.

Answer (score 0):

Just make the link (`<a></a>`) that opens the client information have a `target = "_blank"`:

```
<a href="Clients/Details/1" target="_blank"> John Smith </a>
```

If you are using Html helpers it could be like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("John Smith", "Details", "Clients", new {id = 1}, new { target = "_blank"})
```

This will open a new browser tab with the page you need.

Answer (score 0):

This won't be possible by just using native MVC 4. However, one could think of some work-arounds which might resemble your requirements. For starters, is it necessary to actually open a 'browser tab' per client, or could this also be a tab page per client in one single HTML-document. If the latter is an option, you could take a look at different 'tab' controls being available in HTML.

If your really want a new browser window per client, my hint would be to return the list of possible clients to one HTML page and then use scripting in that HTML page to open a popup window for each client. For each popup / client  an additional request needs to be send to the server.

Comment: Yes, I want a new browser window per client to be open automatically from the controller. So for this scripting you are talking about using AJAX?

Comment: No. You don't need to use AJAX, unless you would like to use JQuery ore something like that to create an in-page popup or something like that. You can simply use scripting over an array of client names / id's to dynamically create an URL to open in a new window. Take a look at the answer from C Sharper. He uses a different approach, but with the same result. Either way you would have to use scripting on the client side.